# Row layout does not work on nested composites

Tags: java, swt

This is what I am trying to achieve, using SWT:

[image: The goal]

For this, I am trying to use `RowLayout` for a nested `Composite`, to wrap the composite's controls depending on the available space. The following code works perfectly:

```
public class RowLayoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("SWT RowLayout test");

        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Label " + i);
        }

        shell.setSize(400, 250);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

This is displayed (please notice the nice wrap of the last labels on the next line - also, on shell resize, the components wraps into available horizontal space):

[image: Row layout on shell works!]

When I do this, instead:

```
public class RowLayoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("SWT RowLayout test");

        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Label(comp, SWT.NONE).setText("Label " + i);
        }

        shell.setSize(400, 250);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

I got the following behaviour. If I resize the shell, the labels are not wrapping into multiple lines.

[image: Row layout no longer works on shell control]

In the below picture, we can see that the composite expands out of the shell client's area, instead of wrapping into second row. Resizing the shell doesn't affect this wrong behaviour.

[image]

I am using the following SWT version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So, why the second scenario is not working? Furthermore, is it possible to use `GridLayout` for shell, but `RowLayout` for a child of this shell?

Comment: You can mix layouts however you like.

Comment: OK, that was my guess also, but why is the nested composite RowLayout not working, while the shell's RowLayout is?

Comment: Probably something to do with how the Shell RowLayout asks the child Composite to compute its size.

Comment: Most probably is size-related, but I want to achieve a solution where the shell's layout is irrelevant (in fact, I do want to use GridLayout for shell and RowLayout for the child composite). How would you correct the above code then?

Comment: Trying to wrap things like this is not something I ever do so I don't have a solution. There are several other SWT experts who may know.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior of the second example on Windows. My guess is that the Composite does not fill the shells client area. Can you give the Composite a distinctive color and update the screenshot? BTW, if you want a control to fill its parents' client area, use a `FillLayout`.

Comment: I have updated the question. I didn't test the behaviour on Windows, only on MacOS, but I need a cross-platform solution anyway. As you can see, the inner composite expands out of shell's client area, instead of wrapping, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using a `GridLayout` as the `Shell`'s layout:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("SWT RowLayout test");

    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    comp.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new Label(comp, SWT.NONE).setText("Label " + i);
    }

    shell.setSize(400, 250);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Produces the same result as your first example.

The "trick" is to set the `GridData` to the child of the element with the `GridLayout`.

Comment: Awesome response! The LayoutData was necessary, but not sufficient in my case. I also has a search Text on the same composite that I was setting the RollLayout() to, and this search text had a GridData set to it. This was the main problem, and gives me an error in RollLayout, as it's constructor expects that all children of this container have a RowData instead. I was wondering in the dark for the whole day because of this. Thank you very much!

Comment: One important note: this only worked for me when the GridData's `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` was `true`; if that was `false`, all my widgets showed up on a single row.